# Too many documents: an index cannot exceed 2147483519 but readers have total maxDoc=2147483531

Tags: solr, cassandra, lucene, datastax-enterprise

Looking for better solution to avoid lucene's hard limit on total doc's. Is there a way to increase the limit.

We are running DSE Search on one of the Datacenter and we are hitting the lucene's hard limit on number of Documents.

**Possible solutions thought were:**
1) Add new node, so data gets redistributed with new tokens and search can be functional. Not viable for this in our case as of now.
2) Decomission one of the node and rebuild the node by **increase the num_token so that it can accomodate lucene docs in more number of partitions(**Its my assumption)**.

**FYI:** I know that DSE prefers single token for Search but my organisation is using virtual token system.

**Below is the actual log from system log file.**

```
 Caused by: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: Too many documents: an index cannot exceed 2147483519 but readers have total maxDoc=2147483531 (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(MMapIndexInput(path="/data/cassandra/data/solr.data/keyspace.table_name/index/segments_2lj")))
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: Updated question, looking for a better solution with the current configuration in our production env.

Comment: Have you considered using SolrCloud and sharding your index?

Comment: We are using DSE 5.1.3, implies Apache Solr™ 6.0.1.0.1833. Not sure if it supports SolrCloud. But with DSE i believe if we use the virtual tokens it also creates shards for that token ranges. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You're limited by Lucene that can't have more than 2B documents in the single index. You can decrease number of documents by:

1. Adding new nodes to cluster (as you already mentioned);
2. Not indexing UDTs that are indexed as separate documents

Comment: Is there any solution like this for DSE http://doc.elassandra.io/en/latest/mapping.html#partitioned-index

Comment: Unfortunately, no :-(

Comment: But I suppose you also can change amount of primary shards, correct? For new indexes. The same amount of nodes but more primary shard.

Comment: In DSE search shard = node, so you need to add more nodes to fix that...